# Make DWR pass a null value, rather than converting to false

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, dwr

I am working with DWR inside the context of a Spring 3.x Web MVC application, where my `dwr-beans.xml` file declares a bean like this:

```
<dwr:configuration>
    <dwr:convert type="bean" class="com.mypackage.Customer"/>
</dwr:configuration>
```

The `com.mypackage.Customer` class has one attribute of type `Boolean` (the object wrapper, not a `boolean` primitive).

This attribute has three different states that are meaningful to the business logic.  It can be true or false, obviously... but a `null` value is meaningful for signaling that a selection hasn't be made yet.

Unfortunately, when a Java object is passed across to JavaScript through a DWR AJAX call... a `null` value shows up as `false` on the JavaScript object.  I'm losing that third meaningful "neither of the above" state.

Google searching has not been very fruitful, unfortunately.  Does anyone know if there is a way to make DWR properly pass across a Java `null` as a JavaScript `null` (or `undefined`)?  Or might I be doing something wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that DWR **does** handle null values correctly by default. My issue was further up the stack... not between the browser and the app server, but rather between the app server and the remote web service that it was calling for the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of code, that can be found in `PrimitiveConverter` of DWR source code

```
if (paramType == Boolean.class)
{
    if (trimValue.length() == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return (T) Boolean.valueOf(trimValue);
}
```

Whenever you pass `null`, `asd` or anything else you've get null as result. You can try to extend DWR with your own implementation, it could be rather tricky. Or use `String` instead in your bean with 3 state ("true", "false", "null").

Comment: Your last sentence is something that's crossed my mind, but I'm not sure where to begin as far as plugging a "custom converter" class into DWR somewhere...